# Assign specific text from another file to pop up display html

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I have a list of lab tests in an html. I would like to click on a lab test to display a pop up window that describes the test in more detail.

I am currently using this code for the pop up (and some css not shown)

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Test title goes here</h2>
      <a href="#close" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a> <!--CHANGED  TO "#close"-->
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Test description goes here. Would like to assign this to specific test description.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#close" class="btn">Go away!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
```

I display the pop up with:

```
<ul>
  <li id="CBC"><a href="#modal-one">Complete blood count</a></li>
  <li id="ferritin"><a href="#modal-one">Ferritin</a></li>
</ul>
```

As it is written, obviously the default text is written into the dialog box.

Now I could make a pop ups specific for each test, but that clearly is neither elegant nor compact code.

Any suggestions on how I would:

1. Set up a file containing the test title (key) and description (value) and what format.
2. Access those key-value pairs to display in the pop up?

Apologies in advance if too simple a question, but I have looked for days here and other places. Such a newbie to websites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-en.html) for that, it resembles basically a JS-Object in file. For example:

```
{
    title: "Title",
    description: "desc"
}
```

To access this object, you have to load it by one of the many ajax functions JavaScript provides you. I'll make examples of jQuery's $.getJSON and the standard JavaScript XMLHttpRequest.

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("path/to/json", function(result) {
    $(".modal-header h2").text(result.title);
    $(".modal-body p").text(result.description);
});
```

Standard JavaScript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        document.querySelector(".modal-header h2").innerHTML = json.title;
        document.querySelector(".modal-body p").innerHTML = json.description;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "path/to/json", true);
xhttp.send();
```